# rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rsync

Guys this is an error I am getting when I try sending files to a server. I am not sure what went wrong. Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
$ rsync -avz ./ ssc:/webapp/

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.4dev]
```

Answer (score 4):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270793

i add "-e /usr/bin/ssh"  and it fixed the issue.

rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh -vP /c/projects/cpp/RecFileExtractBatch/example_recfile_extract_command_file.xml thtran@p811:/home/thtran/mnt_win_pdatx_linux

Answer (score 2):

I'm using cygwin rsync on Windows 11. I'm still not 100% sure why this only started failing for me recently, but I found that using Windows OpenSSH with cygwin rsync was causing the error.

I wound up installing OpenSSH for cygwin and moved `C:\cygwin\bin` before `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\` in my Path in Environment Variables. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

GentlemanJohn's answer was extremely helpful for me. I took his advice but I used `/user/bin/ssh` instead of revising my path. As in:

```bash
$ rsync -avz -e "/bin/ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa" --progress ads@35.222.105.182:/ads/qsmrp/ qsmrp
```

(The trailing slash on the qsmrp directory indicates copy its content only.)

The Windows version of openssh prevented rsync from working (0 bytes transferred).

Answer (score 0):

Remove OpenSSH-Cliente on ''Settings' > 'Apps' > 'Optional Features', install Git and add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to Windows PATH. and ensure then rsync and ssh have the same paths, use 'where ssh' and 'where rsync' to check that.